# convert text table structure into lists

Tags: python

can someone tell me how to convert table like below :

```
    Device      Type       Model          Description      Vendor
   --------------------------------------------------------------
    Device1    Network1     Model2       Network Device1     bla bla
    Device2    Network2     Model2       Network Device2     bla bla
```

to be something like below :

```
Device = [Device1, Device2]
Type = [Network1, Network1]
Model = [Model2, Model2]
Description = [Network Device1 , Network Device2]
Vendor = [bla bla, bla bla]
```

i tried to use :

```
networkdata = open("./bin/data.txt",'r').read()
for row in networkdata:
    row = networkdata.rstrip('\n').split(" ")
    networkdataTable= [r.strip() for r in row if r != '']
```

but no luck, can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Could you tell if the big spaces between:
"Device1    Network1     Model2       Network Device1     bla bla"
Is <tab> '\t'? or is space?

Comment: Hi, they are spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## updated answer:

I am going to take the wonderful solution that @kaya3 gave to use regex and include it in my answer.

```
import re
txt = '''\
    Device     Type         Model        Description         Vendor
   --------------------------------------------------------------
    Device1    Network1     Model2       Network Device1     bla bla
    Device2    Network2     Model2       Network Device2     bla bla'''

Device      = []
Type        = []
Model       = []
Description = []
Vendor      = []

for i,t in enumerate(txt.split('\n')):
    if i< 2: continue  #ignore header and the line with ---
    x = re.split(r'\s\s+', t.strip())

    Device.append(x[0].strip())
    Type.append(x[1].strip())
    Model.append(x[2].strip())
    Description.append(x[3].strip())
    Vendor.append(x[4].strip())

print (Device)
print (Type)
print (Model)
print (Description)
print (Vendor)
```

Output will be same. In this case, we are just extracting data into separate fields if it has more than one space.

The output of this will be:

```
['Device', 'Device1', 'Device2']
['Type', 'Network1', 'Network2']
['Model', 'Model2', 'Model2']
['Description', 'Network Device1', 'Network Device2']
['Vendor', 'bla bla', 'bla bla']
```

## previous answer:

You can iterate through the string and extract the data by position.

```
d = []
for t in txt.split('\n'):
    y = []
    y.append(t[4:11].strip())
    y.append(t[15:23].strip())
    y.append(t[27:35].strip())
    y.append(t[35:60].strip())
    y.append(t[60:].strip())
    d.append(y)
d.pop(1)
print (d)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[['Device', 'Type', 'Model', 'Description', 'Vendor'], ['Device1', 'Network1', 'Model2', 'Network Device1', 'bla bla'], ['Device2', 'Network2', 'Model2', 'Network Device2', 'bla bla']]
```

If you want to store them into separate variables you can give:

```
Device      = []
Type        = []
Model       = []
Description = []
Vendor      = []

for x in d:
    Device.append(x[0])
    Type.append(x[1])
    Model.append(x[2])
    Description.append(x[3])
    Vendor.append(x[4])


print (Device)
print (Type)
print (Model)
print (Description)
print (Vendor)
```

The output of this will be:

```
['Device', 'Device1', 'Device2']
['Type', 'Network1', 'Network2']
['Model', 'Model2', 'Model2']
['Description', 'Network Device1', 'Network Device2']
['Vendor', 'bla bla', 'bla bla']
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked with me with above example, but what if these spaces are different .. would it matter ? i mean instead of having 10 spaces between each cell, they are 15 or less ?

Comment: see my updated code at the bottom. It is almost doing the same thing that @kaya3 did. Instead of using zip, I am storing them separately.

Comment: Updated post to show answer in the top section

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that columns are separated by multiple spaces, and there are no "empty" cells, you could do this:

```py
import re

with open("./bin/data.txt") as f:
    rows = map(str.strip, f)
    networkdata_table = [re.split(r'\s\s+', row) for row in rows if row][2:]
    # slice [2:] removes first two lines, which are the table header

Device, Type, Model, Description, Vendor = zip(*networkdata_table)
```

The two important parts are `re.split(r'\s\s+', ...)` which splits a string on any occurrence of two or more whitespace characters, and `zip(*...)` which converts the "rows" of the nested list into "columns".

Note that you should generally use a `with` block to open a file, it is not necessary to specify `'r'` as the mode to open the file with since that is the default, and you can iterate over a file-handle object `f` directly to get one line at a time.

Comment: i tried this. I think the strip() will strip `Network Device2` as two items.

Comment: `strip()` only removes whitespace from the start and end of the row. It does not do anything with whitespace between words. The splitting is only done by `re.split`, and this regex matches two or more spaces, not a single space.

Comment: sorry, i meant split(). I am testing the code. I tried split instead

Comment: first i want to thank you for ur assistance, 2nd .. i tried the code but giving me this error:  
    Device, Type, Model, Description, Vendor = zip(*networkdata_table)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 1)

Comment: @kaya3 wonderful solution. Your code returns correct data but it's in form of tuple whereas the requirement is to have output as list.

Comment: @HetalThaker The question doesn't say it's a requirement for the results to be lists, the question says *"something like below"*. If there is a need to edit the contents of the results later, you can just write `map(list, zip(*networkdata_table))` instead.

Comment: @kaya3 In the title of the question it says convert text table structure into lists, anyways you have already suggested a solution for that too. Thank you.

Comment: @Levir *"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 1)"* would occur if your file has empty lines or possibly if it has some lines with just one column. Please see my edit. However, the answer you accepted should have the same problem, since it accesses `x[1]` through `x[4]` also without checking if the row is empty.